# Use setInverval to perform GET requests to nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, get, http2

I'm using nodejs with express to read a collection in mongodb for a set of messages to display to the user. I've read about http2, but I don't know if there are any significant advantages over using setInterval on the client side to receive an updated message list. I'm basically doing:

```
setInterval(()=>{ 
            this.props.getSession(session_id);
        }, 5000);
```

This takes the _id of the mongodb document and sends it in a GET request to nodejs every 5 seconds. Is this going to cause serious problems in the wild. I'm basically terrified that this will cause horrible performance issues at scale, but I'm wondering what alternatives I have besides what looks like an incredible complicated http2 implementation that could have many security vulnerabilities.

I guess I could also rephrase my question as, will this cause my server to crash with a small number of users running this code on a certain page?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing what the specs of the server are. However, you might be able to find the answer yourself if you deploy your change progressively, in order to understand how that affects your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured out the best way to deal with this, and it is not helpful to focus too much on how the messages exist in the database. I ended up using a web-socket library called socket.io. I was able to create unique "rooms" for each group that connects to the server when the page loads. The mongodb _id for the message session is used to dynamically create a room as follows:

```
io.on('connection', async function(socket){
    socket.on('session' async (session)=>{
        socket.join(session.session_id); //not shown: session join authentication
    });
    socket.on('send', async (d)=>{


        try{
            const {text} = d.body;
            const {token, session} = d.head;
            //custom function that is async to parse jwt token and do db.MessageSession.create({})
            const result = await socketMeassageAuthAndSend(session, token, text);
            const {flag, user, _id, date} = result;

            if(flag === 'auth'){
               socket.broadcast.to(session).emit('socket_message_broadcast', {text,user,_id,date})
             }else{
               socket.emit("unauthorized", {message: "will place ip address here to send to admin panel"});
             }}catch(err){
                 console.log(err);
               }
     });
```

This works to perform updates that are authenticated and authorized with a mongo database. There is no need for event driving from mongoose and it keeps the database synchronized with the user's view in real time.